# show the file names for files changed using sed, like what grep displays

Tags: macos, sed, terminal, grep, find

I'm using the Mac OSX Terminal and using find then exec a sed on the files.  How do i get it to list out the files that have been changed?

This is what I'm using:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec sed -i '' 's/_persistenceURL = "prod"/_persistenceURL = "qa"/g' {} +
```

and I like how this outputs a list of files that match...  can i get this from the sed?

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec grep -lr "_persistenceURL = \"prod\""  {} \;
```

Comment: So you are providing a list of files for `sed` to work on, but you want to know which of those files actually changed?

Comment: yes that's pretty much the gist

Comment: or at least show the find's progression of files as it works through the thousands of files.

Comment: And you're running this from an app of some sort?

Comment: the Mac OS Terminal on a folder on a network drive

Comment: It's possible that `sed` returns a different exit code when it's replaced something (like `grep` does when it finds a match) so you could check for that.  As far as progress is concerned, can't you just echo the directory you are currently working on?

Comment: I'm new to this all, so i'm not really sure what's possible, i've just been googling all morning about getting it to work.  It's running recursively at the root level of a network drive containing hundreds of folder and thousands of files.  Can I echo the file/directory that it's performing the sed on?

Comment: Of course; but rather than running `sed` directly from `find`, get `find` to create your list of files to work on , and then process each file in turn using `sed`, `echo`ing the current file as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quick and dirty way of doing it by adding a second `-exec` action to the find statment which echoes the filename before sed processes it:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec echo "{}" \; -exec sed -i '' 's/_persistenceURL = "prod"/_persistenceURL = "qa"/g' {} +
```

note: the `+` at the end may interfere a bit, so if it's not strictly necessary, i'd replace it with `\;`.

Comment: That seems to work, echoing each file that it finds.  I've taken your syntax for doing that and instead of echoing i put in my grep so it only lists the files that has the content inside that I'm looking for, so a comprehensive list of the files that will be changed by the sed that runs right after finding the file.  Thanks!

    find . -name '*.js' -exec grep -lr '_persistenceURL = "prod"'  {} \; -exec sed -i '' 's/_persistenceURL = "prod"/_persistenceURL = "qa"/g' {} +

Comment: even better! glad to help.

Comment: There's no need for `-exec`.  Just add `-print` before the `-exec`.  But this also prints files that are not changed.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` does not provide a mechanism to return a value, nor does it have access to the filename.  But you can do:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec sh -c \
   'sed "s/_persistenceURL = \"prod\"/_persistenceURL = \"qa\"/g" $0 > $0.$$; \
   if ! cmp $0.$$ $0; then echo $0; mv $0.$$ $0; else rm $0.$$; fi' {} \;
```

It would probably be a lot cleaner to put the command in a script and exec the script.  note that this uses the pid of the internal shell as a suffix for a temporary file.  Be careful, as this may overwrite files.  Put the command in a script and add some checks for things like that.